# unlike() does not work with $ _POST. Desktop application in JAVA with swing send POST to php file

Tags: java, php, swing

Hello and sorry for my bad English.

I have installed xampp( Everything it´s ok). I need to upload and delete some files. I can upload any file. That script works perfectly. The real problems comes when I try to delete the file using `$_POST['archivoAEliminar']`.

This is the script that I use:

```
<?php 
    //error_reporting(0);
    $target_path = "..\\imagenes\\";
    $target_path = $target_path . trim($_POST['imagenAEliminar']," ");



    echo $target_path;
    if (unlink($target_path)) 
    {
        echo "[web]Se elimino correctamente/delete successful .";
    }
    else
    {
        if (is_null($_POST['imagenAEliminar']))
        {
            echo "[web] Es nulo/Its null.";
        }

        echo "[web]Algo sucedio y no se elimino/No delete.";
    }

?>
```

When I "submit" from Java clearly I detect that my code run in Apache server because I have a response, but it´s seems like the path does´t exist. If I copy the same path (the rensponse that server say does´t exist) directly in `unlink('\\imagenes\\image002.jpg')` works and the file is delete.

I deleted the .htacces file and I have installed the server in windows 7. This happen only wen I use $_POST from java in desktop application.

**UPGRADE**

This code does not work to:

```
<?php 
    //error_reporting(0);
    $target_path = "\\imagenes\\";
    $target_path = $target_path.$_POST['imagenAEliminar'];



    echo $target_path;
    if (unlink($target_path)) 
    {
        echo "[web]Se elimino correctamente.";
    }
    else
    {
        if (is_null($_POST['imagenAEliminar']))
        {
            echo "[web] Es nulo.";
        }

        echo "[web]Algo sucedio y no se elimino";
    }

?>
```

Comment: `$target_path = "\\imagenes\\";`  as you said that `unlink('\\imagenes\\image002.jpg')` worked

Comment: Sorry for the "...". Actually does not work to if I replace them. Is the same problem. The script don´t recognize the path 
through the $_POST.

The script work fine stand alone, but when `$_POST['imagenAEliminar']` is used does not work, specially  when I use de java aplication. But the response of the server is the same path that works when I replace directly in the script.

Comment: also `trim($_POST['imagenAEliminar'])` is needed only.

Comment: Sorry, I have a lot code trash . `trim($_POST['image Eliminar'])` is doing nothing, it's no necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! A friend found (in the logs) the reason. The java code that I use append "\r\n" in the end of the string before being sent. Echo in php don´t show this escape characters. I remove the f#%& line that´s appended and everything works fine! Thank you all.

That´s happens when you copy and paste code. As a Mexican saying goes:
**"EL HUEVON TRABAJA DOS VECES."**